# Windows XP Computer Management - Local Users and Groups error

Tags: windows-xp, sp3

I opened Computer Management and happened to see that "Local Users and Groups" (under System Tools) had a red X over top of it. After clicking the link, it shows a message saying "Unable to access the computer EMACHINES-PC. The error was: Library not registered." What could have caused this, and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing the active directory store type library. You can restore it in a few easy steps:

- Download `RegTLB.exe` from [here](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=2195).
- Extract `RegTLB.exe` from `TypeLibrary\Release` (We'll extract it to the `C:\` drive to make it simple)
- Open up command prompt and run this command:

```
C:\RegTLB.exe c:\windows\system32\activeds.tlb
```

- You will get a messagebox saying the type library was successfully created
- Local Users and Groups should now open successfully.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on EMACHINES-PC and Computer Management is local.

Comment: @Wesley answer updated.

Comment: You are a legend

Answer (score 0):

I used Filemon v6.07 and found out that a file called activeds.tlb was missing. After I restored a copy of it into the system32 directory, I was able to access the local users and groups database from the local computer's Computer Management Console again.

the utility Filemon is a monitoring tool lets you see all file system activity in real-time. 
Filemon works on NT 4.0, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows XP 64-bit Edition, Windows 2003 Server, Windows 95, Windows 98 and Windows ME. Sysinternals also has a version of Filemon for Linux.
and is available at:

http://www.sysinternals.com

Comment: How did you "find out"?

Comment: It's an old thread on Computing.net. http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/library-not-registered/82170.html but it worked good for me a while ago. Ihope it help for you.